# Functions are not being called when Python variables are passed into HTML

Tags: python, html, css

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi
import sqlite3
import os


path = '/var/www/html/mahesh1/trishul.db'
con = sqlite3.connect(path)
cur = con.cursor()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print("Content-Type:text/html\n\n")
cur.execute("SELECT * from staff")
p = cur.fetchall()
global NAME
global EMAIL

def ins():
    global to
    print(to)
    cur.execute("UPDATE staff SET password=? WHERE email_id=?", (rnd,to))
    con.commit()

def rand():
    global rnd
    rnd = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for i in range(random.choice([6,7,8,9,10])))

def email(to):
    fromaddr = "dummy.trishul@gmail.com"
    fpwd = "bilbobaggins"       
    body = 'Dear Student, your password has been set to '+rnd+'. Please Login with this password.'
    subj = "Password Issue"       
    print(to)
    yag = yagmail.SMTP(fromaddr, fpwd).send(to, subj, body)

for i in p:
    NAME = i[1]
    EMAIL = i[2]
    html1 = '''
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 1368;
    }

    td {
        text-align:center;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

    th {
        text-align:center;
        padding: 8px;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
    div{
    padding-right:0px;
    }
    div{
    color: #FF0000
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='%s' value='APPROVE'></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>'''%(NAME,EMAIL,EMAIL)
    if NAME in form:
        rand()
        email(EMAIL)
        ins()
    print(html1)
```

Functions are not being called. I am displaying the name, email and approve button on the HTML page from my database through the path. When I click the approve button to a particular email id and name on my HTML page it should send the mail to the respective email id.

Comment: Could you change your code to a minimum, complete and verifiable example, e.g. by removing all of the HTML code that is not related to the question?

Comment: What do the HTML string and the variables inserted into it have to do with the calling of the functions?

Comment: suppose there are 5 members in my database i am able to display their names,email ids and approve buttons but when i click approve button for a particular name and email id the functions should be called and send a mail to the respective email id.

Comment: In your form, you have no action specified. `<form action='myscript.py'>` sends the request to that script, and the server will execute the script giving it the form data as arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its working

Comment: I will add it as an answer then, so that people see that the question has an answer already without having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you have no action specified. `<form action='myscript.py'>` sends the request to that script, and the server will execute the script giving it the form data as arguments.
(Copied from my comment above)